# Datepicker of Bootstrap (Does not highlight the selected date! and hovering over dates does not highlight)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

Im using datepicker of bootstrap and it works fine, but there is some problem for appearance; for exaple when I select a date it does not highlight the date with the blue background and whenever I hover over dates it does not change the background colors as it is supposed to do like : http://jsfiddle.net/6kk3k/1/.

This is my simple HTML:

```
            <input type="text"  class="datepicker" placeholder="Click me!">
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Also I have included bootstrap.js, bootstrap-datepicker.js, datepicker.css and jquery.js!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'); ?>"></script>
<script rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="<?php echo base_url('datepicker/css/datepicker.css'); ?>"></script>
```

What can be the reason that the selected date does not get highlighted and hovering does not work!

If you need more clarification, please just let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Don't show us a fiddle that works, show us one that doesn't with your markup and linked to the actual file versions that you're using

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to jsfiddle! I made it at http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/VyhRF/1/
 it seems I need to mention the direct links for resources; however I could not find any online resources for datepicker.css!

Comment: Now I figured it out! Iwas missing http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css Thanks :-)

Comment: @Pasargad haha luckily I saw this otherwise I would not have  realized as quickly I did `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js" />` :-D

Answer (score 2):

The OP solved their problem by including jQuery UI's `datepicker.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dp3").datepicker({
                todayBtn : true,
                autoclose : true,
                **todayHighlight : true,**
                endDate: "current"
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to reference the datepicker3.css file, and then set todayHighlight to True. Below is my Django implementation. Adapt to fit.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/plugins/datapicker/datepicker3.css" %}">

<script src="{% static "js/plugins/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js" %}"></script>


<script>
       $(function() {
             $(".datepicker1").datepicker({todayHighlight: true});
        });
</script>
```